# EmEditor - How to batch deleting characters from where I want?

Tags: java, python, html, excel, emeditor

I'm new to EmEditor and having a problem with using it freely.

The knottiest problem I couldn't handle now is **batch deleting characters from where I want**.

**I want to know how to batch remove left or right from reference point I set.**

Due to there're tons of rows to edit, and each row has its own various types of characters surrounding my reference point, **'search and remove (or switchover)' won't work for me.**

Here's an example:

```
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td bgcolor=#3366cc><img width=1 height=1 alt=""></td></tr></table>
```

I want to set the below part as my reference point.

```
<img width=1 height=1 alt="">
```

If to delete left, the below code should've removed.

```
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td bgcolor=#3366cc>
```

If to delete right, the below code should've removed.

```
</td></tr></table>
```

Like I mentioned up there, search and the switchover is not a good idea for me.

And I'm not trying to count numbers from reference point either.

There should be an easy way to do what I want. Please help me!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If everything is one line such as in the example, then regex will work. (Make sure to select the "Regular Expressions" option in replace window)

Search `.*(?=<img width=1 height=1 alt="">)` for text before reference point.

Search `(?<=<img width=1 height=1 alt="">).*` for text after reference point. Then replace with empty string. Does that work?

Comment: It works! I checked regular expressions button and restarted software, then worked just fine as I wanted. Thank you very much!!!